# react-query 3 setQueryData doesn't update the cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I have this query:

```
export function useCardList() {
  return useQuery(['cardList'], fetchCardList());
}
```

I'm using it in my component:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useCardList();

// delete 
 const handleOnDelete = (id: string) => {
    const newData = {
      ...data,
      data: data?.data.filter((card) => card.id !== id)
    };
    queryClient.setQueryData(['cardList'], newData);
};
```

but `setQueryData` doesn't work. what do you think? (edited)

Comment: Do you get any data when you call the `useCardList`? Can you show that data? It's hard to know what the structure is that you are trying to update.

Comment: Yeah, i get data when i call that @TomasVancoillie.

Comment: Can you log that data? Plus are you not making a mutation for the database?

Comment: This question doesn't show enough info to be answered. Where is the queryClient coming from? Why is `fetchCardList` invoked immediately? Please show a full reproduction